# AngularJS - UIGrid - How to read data for a selected row?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

In my Angular apps I am using UI Grid  (http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial)

How do I get the data of the selected row ?

Plunker :  http://plnkr.co/edit/GpsfCHewYjhiPcwAQheA?p=preview

HTML:

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection class="grid"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [grid selection module](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.selection.api:PublicApi) has a method to get the selected rows: `getSelectedRows()`.

You can access this method through the `gridApi` if you define your options like so:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: $scope.columns,
  onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
  }
};
```

Comment: Very helpful. Are there any events triggered on selecting a checkbox? I want to get the primary key of the selected row.

Comment: There is a `rowSelectionChanged` event which should suit your requirement. (http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.selection.api:PublicApi)